# How to calculate total moment around $z$-axis when the armlengths are not the same for all motors on a hexacopter?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum, torque, angular-velocity

I wonder how I can calculate the total moment around $z$-axis at a given rotational velocity for the motors on a hexacopter. My intuition tells me that motors that are more distant to center of mass should have greater effect on the total moment around $z$-axis, therefore I need to multiply the armlengths with the torque generated by the motor at a certain speed to get a weighted sum. However I cannot find any physical foundation to support my intuition. Also the calculations I have seen online just sum all torque values without taking armlengths into account. Can you explain how these work?

Comment: Okay I get it intuitively. When the distance is greater, less force is required to compensate the effect of motor on the stability of the system. Which means torque is the same no matter how distant motor is from the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as moments or torques about the "same" axis, you just add them up.

The location is only important for forces.

Comment: Then each motor has the same effect on the yaw no matter how distant it is from the center of mass, right?

Comment: Yes, to the extent of the torques produced by the motor. But the motor shaft reaction forces (if any) need to be considered also with $\sum_i r_i \times F_i$

Comment: I thought, the reactive torque which is I am asking about, is the result of motor shaft reaction forces according to Newton's 3rd law. What do you mean by motor shaft reaction forces? @JAlex